# My code shows a typeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

This is simply like a "scratch" code for a game i'm making (a simple connect4 game), im just trying out the functionality of my functions.

Basically, the error i get is TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable on line 25. 
Here is my code:

```
def play():
    grid_height = int(input("Enter the number of rows:")) #Row
    grid_width = int(input("Enter the number of columns:")) #Width
    p1_char= 'e'


    grid(grid_height,grid_width)
    displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)
    updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char)
    displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)

def grid(grid_height,grid_width):
    grid=[]
    for row in range(grid_height): # FOR ROW
        z =[]
        for col in range(grid_width): # FOR COLUMN
            z.append(" ")
        grid.append(z)
    return grid

def displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width): 
    for row in range(grid_height):
        for col in range(grid_width+1):
            print("|" + grid[row-1][col-1],end = "")
        print()
    print(" "+" ".join([str(i) for i in range(1, 8+1)]))
    return grid

def updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char):
    move= int(input('Enter your move: '))
    for i in range(grid_height+1):
        grid[grid_height-1][move-1]= p1_char
        break
    return grid

play()
```

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: @wwii Oh! Okay, thank you! Sorry, i'm new here. Ill do it next time!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues here:

1. You have a function called `grid`, and you frequently use local variables called `grid`. This is causing some confusion. Consider renaming `grid` to `createGrid`.
2. When you call `grid` (aka `createGrid`) in `play()`, you are not assigning the return value to a variable. As a result, you end up passing the *function* `grid` to `displayGrid` and `updateGrid`, which results in the error you're seeing.

Comment: I realized my mistakes after posting. I will update the post, but i now have a new question

Comment: Oh wait, you cant edit posts, ill just post a new one